# how to really exit an activity which contain fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, exit, onbackpressed

I have3 Activities.
The first one A contains a Fragment A1 which contains a Spinner.
When I click the Spinner i ll go to Activity B, which contains a Button.
When I click the Button will go to Activity C.

I ovverrode the Activity C's OnBackPressed

```
(
Super OnBackPressed()
Intent i = new intent (this,ActivityB.class)
Finish();
StartActivity i
}
```

I overrode the Activity B's OnBackPressed

```
(
    Super OnBackPressed()
    Intent i = new intent (this,ActivityA.class)
    Finish();
    StartActivity i
    }
```

I overrode the Activity A's OnBackPressed

```
(
Super OnBackPressed()
Finish();
}
```

My problem is that each time I click on Android's return Button when I am in Activity A, the application doesn't exit and goes to my old Spinner choice.
I have to click several times to really quit.

What should I do to leave the application by simply clicking on the Android return Button when I am in the Fragment A1?

Comment: use this if you want to close your application.  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getActivity().finish();` from `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to finish the current activity before moving to other one.

For ex: When in Activity A, you click on spinner, inside onclick you start activity B and then call finish(); This will start Activity B and finish Activity A.

This way you will end up with one activity throughout. Once u back press, you will directly come out of the application.

Comment: i call the Activity B through the Fragmetn A1 so how can i do it since i cant wirte finish int fragment?

Comment: You need to call finish using getActivity().finish();

getActivity() will get the parent activity context for the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In Activity A, you can do this to make sure you clear your backstack, so your app doesn't go the old spinner choice.

In your onCLickListener

```
Context context = view.getContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // call this to finish the current activity
```

or you can also, do that in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityA" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

Comment: the OnclickListener is on the Fragment A1 so i cant do a finish();

Comment: Then, you should use android:noHistory="true" in your Activity xml manifest